# Django - search a text field for a word or phrase contained in another model

Tags: django

What would be the best method for setting up a keyword finder as below?

```
 class scene(models.Model):
        fk_type = models.ForeignKey(scene_types, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        text = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
        order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order', )


class AI_keywords(models.Model):

    fk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    response = models.ForeignKey(AI_responses, default='1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('keyword', )
```

views

```
class v_scene(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = scene
    template_name = 'storiesapp/scene.html'
    context_object_name = 'scene'
```

The idea is when a keyword in the AI_keywords model is detected in the scene.text field, it displays the AI_keywords.response field

Comment: when you tell " display the AI_keywords.response field " is on template html file ?

Comment: Obviously going through every `AI_keywords` and checking against every entry in `scene` would be expensive.  You could add Django signal handlers to detect when models change and then add other models to cache those results.  (ex a new `AI_keyword` is added so you cycle through all `scene` for that keyword and record which ones it's in; perhaps in a many-to-many table). If this is still too expensive, then you could offload it to another machine with celery.

Comment: @Tim Tisdall - great points but it only has to check the AI_keywords model for one scene record as the scene.html is a detail view. Once a user selects a scene from a scene list html, they're taken to a page showing the textbox for only that scene and this is where i'd like these results to appear. I could even simply implement a button to update the query, it doesn't have to be automatically updated.

Comment: @rgermain yes, it's on the scene's html called scene.html